# Extending protocols for custom Java classes, maps and sequences in Clojure

Tags: java, data-structures, clojure, protocols

I have created a protocol in Clojure 1.2 that handles my own Java classes and has default handling for a generic java.lang.Object. The code looks something like:

```
(extend-protocol PMyProtocol
  my.java.ClassName
    (protocol-function [c]
      "My Java class result")

  java.lang.Object
    (protocol-function [c]
      "Default object result"))
```

How should I extend this to have special handling for the standard Clojure data structures (in particular maps, vectors and sequences)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All of Clojure's persistent data structures implement interfaces which extend `clojure.lang.PersistentCollection`. Clojure's transient collections implement `clojure.lang.TransientCollection`. You can extend your protocol to these as if you were extending it to a class (though dealing with just the persistent collections might make more sense).

Comment: To name them explicitly in case different handling is necessary: `c.l.IPersistentMap`, `c.l.IPersistentVector`, `c.l.IPersistentSet` (there is some system in there...) and for sequences `c.l.ISeq`.

Comment: Thanks Michal and kotarak! I ended up using clojure.lang.IPersistentMap and clojure.lang.ISeq which are working well.